# set endpoint of an OSGI Blueprint file in ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix

I know I can define Camel routes in stand-alone xml file, using the Blueprint syntax. If I move one of this file in the "deploy" folder of ServiceMix, it automatically becomes an OSGI bundle. My question is, can I set an endpoint to this new bundle, accessible from outside?

I would like to do something like this:

blue_route1.xml

```
<blueprint>
  <camelContext>
    <route>
      <from uri="http:my_servicemix:8181/blue_route1_endpoint" />
      <to uri="jetty:http://server1" />
    </route>
  </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

blue_route1 becomes an OSGI bundle once deployed, but where should I define "blue_route1_endpoint" ?  Is it doable?

[UPDATE]

summering, I want that an external WS is able to send messages to *blue_route1_endpoint*, where the *blue_route1* bundle will redirect messages according to Camel routes, without the need to create a new WS "*Blue_route1*" to deploy in ServiceMix

```
                                   ______________________
                                   |     ____________   |
external-->(blue_route1_endpoint)==|==-->|blue_route1|--|-->(http://server1)
  WS                               |     |___________|  |
                                   |____________________|
                                          ServiceMix
```

Comment: What do you mean accessible from the outside, do you mean using HTTP? Then instead of http use jetty or servlet component.

Comment: I want that an external WebService is able to send to it SOAP messages. Is it possible, or I need to create a "fake" WS to deploy in ServiceMix, in order to redirect messages using the camel routes? I updated the question trying to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I didn't get that it's so easy. To make ServiceMix listen on a port, I just have to specify the endpoint using the Camel-jetty component.
So, to answer my question, I solved in this way:

install the camel-jetty component in ServiceMix

```
features:install camel-jetty
```

Write the camel-route with Blueprint, in blue_route1.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
            <from uri:="jetty:http:my_servicemix:8181/blue_route1_endpoint">
            <to uri="http://localhost:8080/user/services/user?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
        </route>
        <route>
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:6969/sp_role?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
            <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
                <groovy>"text/xml; charset=utf-8"</groovy>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="http://server1"/>
        </route>        
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

I used a random port 8181 to listen to... but I could choose every number, ServiceMix will automatically start a jetty component, listening and consuming on that port/endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

For SOAP messages you need [CXF Component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) and wsdl file of your webservice. You can configure your endpoint outside of the camelContext like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="yourId" address="/your/address/to/endpoint"
    serviceClass="your.java.ServiceClass"
    wsdlURL="path/to/your/wsdl/file.wsdl" />
```

And in your route use  tag like this:

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:yourId"/>
```

You need to add namespace and schemaLocation to your blueprint to use cxf namespace, use this:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
```